# JQuery Get Value of Embedded Widget Autocomplete Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager

I have embedded a widget into my site provided by a third party site, this widget displays an input box that auto-suggests text to the user on input.

It's the same as the `Ask Your Question` search on [this page](https://tblc.libanswers.com/index.php?).

I embed the widget by including a `widget.js` file in my document `<head>`, and calling it in my html with;

`<div id="widget-5032"></div>`

When I inspect the HTML of the widget I see the following (sample item list);

```
<div>
    <ul id="search-query-5032_list">
        <li data-question="Alaska">Alaska</li>
        <li data-question="Hawaii">Hawaii</li>
        <li data-question="etc.">etc.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The auto-suggestions are being served from the third party website, when one is clicked, the input is populated with the suggested text and the page automatically redirects to the external website (no need to click the `search` button). I have no control over how the widget functions.

I'm trying to capture the value of the selected text but I'm not sure how to?

The reason I want to do this is so I can send it to Google Tag Manager using `dataLayer.push({})`

I've tried this but it doesn't work;

```
$('#search-query-5032_list li').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is the service you're using for auto-suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look at the code on the page and I think you can use this piece of code on your page. The Try/Catch is important as the hidden input is only created when an item is selected.

```
springSpace.la.widget_5032_inst.search.autocomplete.input.parentNode.addEventListener('click', function(){

try {
    alert(searchform_5032.form.querySelector('input[name=faqid]').value);
}
catch(err) {
    console.log("empty");
}

});
```

Where I have the "alert" message, you would replace with your GTM dataLayer push to get that information into GTM/GA.

Comment: Thanks for the help @XTOTHEL, but it's not working. I don't use any initiation code, I simply include a widget.js file (which looks like this https://pastebin.com/wjHGjggw), then insert one line of html `<div id="widget-5032"></div>`.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I made the adjustment, I based my solution on the working example here: https://www.aclib.us/

Comment: Thanks again @XTOTHEL but now i'm getting errors `(index):608 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined`, and `Uncaught ReferenceError: searchform_5032 is not defined`. I'll keep trying though based on your sample :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

```js
$('#search-query-5032_list').on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <ul id="search-query-5032_list">
        <li data-question="Alaska">Alaska</li>
        <li data-question="Hawaii">Hawaii</li>
        <li data-question="etc.">etc.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm you then didnt provide us correct info. did you try this sample?

Comment: hmm as you can see it is simple stuff in my sample it is important that you have correct ul id  and also to have correct reference to jquery library. My sample here shows ul li value in popup, doesn't? if does then you have another problem there why i3t not works on your sides, we dont see that?

Comment: I understand your logic, and if the code wasn't an embedded widget i'm sure your sample code would work. However the code I am using is in the form of a dynamically added widget, does this make any difference?

Comment: yes there can be a difference did you read about customizing a widgets in that case, maybe there is something else you should do, some additional steps for settings except write few lines of js?